# Compare two items in list to multiple lists with two values and return boolean values

Tags: python, python-3.5

I am attempting to match a single control list containing two items to multiple target lists that also contain two values each. I have achieved this in the below code, but i cannot figure out how to return multiple lists with the boolean results for each list comparison.

```
value = [2.55, 5.55]

a = [2.55, 3.55]
b = [4.55, 5.55]
c = [6.55, 7.68]

check = [i for i in value if i in a + b + c]
print (check)
```

I would like the result to be something like: (this is the desired output)..

```
#a = [true, false]
#b = [false, true]
#c = [false, false]
```

thank you

Comment: I don't quite get it. Why are the results of a, b, c the way they are? the result for a makes sense I guess. But, b and c don't. I'm not sure what your final result is based off?

Comment: I think the result was just an example of format, not based off the input.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the question to make sense as per the desired result. This code: `check = [[val in lst for val in value] for lst in [a, b, c]]` was just posted and does exactly what i want, but I am having trouble understanding it in comprehension format

Comment: Added a code belowe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know if this is what you want and if there is a mistake in your logic, but this might do the work:

```
value = [2.55, 5.55]

a = [2.55, 3.55]
b = [4.55, 5.55]
c = [6.55, 7.68]

# comprehension
result = [[val in lst for val in value] for lst in [a, b, c]]
# without comprehension
result = []
for lst in [a, b, c]:
    row = []
    for val in value:
        row.append(val in lst)
    result.append(row)

# if u want to asign the lists to the a, b, c, u can do instead
a, b, c = [[val in lst for val in value] for lst in [a, b, c]]
print(a, b, c)
[True, False] [False, True] [False, False]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
A,B,C = [[abc_value == val_value for abc_value, val_value in zip(abc, value)] for abc in [a,b,c]]
```

Of course, it will be less ugly with a better naming convention and storing `a, b, c` in a list initlally.

[zip()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip)

(The solution above complies with my understanding of what you want to achieve only as much as my mind reading abilities allow it.)